# Ads in game made with Unity Basic?

Tags: unity-game-engine, payment, ads

It is possible to use any ads on my games made with Uniy **Basic** (or make it as pay application in Play Store)?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a software feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Check the Unity Asset store, there are several free and paid tools you can use to add advertisement to your game. You can also create your own subsystem that handles this.

Also it is perfectly legal.

Comment: Thanks, good to know this! But can i legally send my game as pay application to Play Store?

Comment: @DzieckoBezZycia yes it is legal.

Comment: Please, could you clarify the part about creating a paid application, and also add references for the answer?